# Google Glass Not on App Engine

Tags: python, google-mirror-api

Has anyone tried to get a glassware running on a server besides the App Engine, like Tomcat for example?

I am trying to get a glassware app going and I would rather avoid using the Google App Engine itself. I'm having difficulties approaching this and I will be using Tomcat as my server.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The PHP quick start runs on whatever PHP environment you have handy. Are you looking for a specific language? (Based on Tomcat I assume you want something in Java?)

Comment: If you can give specifics about the difficulties you're encountering, it would be helpful. If you're having problems with Java specifically, there was a similar question in the past few days that discussed the packages you would need to replace. But you can certainly run Glass on non-appengine servers.

Comment: I'm going to be writing this on python, no difficulties yet just wanted to see if other explorers had approached this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No problems so far running outside of App Engine for me. I stood up the example in App Engine just to get my bearings. Once I saw how it behaved I had enough information to distill it down to what I would need to run it outside of App Engine.

Here's your checklist:

1. You need to create a project in https://code.google.com/apis/console
2. You need to add Mirror API to the services (at this moment, only available to Glass Explorers-- if I'm not mistaken)
3. Under API Access you need to create a Client ID for Web Applications; set up your redirect URL to point to the enrollment servlet you're going to create.
4. Create your enrollment service that handles the oAuth 2.0 dance and stores tokens. You can probably appropriate most of the code from the example app and implement your own credential store or use the in-memory one from Google...
5. Enroll yourself in your own app and use your credentials to develop your Mirror API app.

I was able to eliminate the App Engine dependencies from my pom file, but I still needed to keep google-http-client-jackson, google-oauth-client, guava, and of course google-api-services-mirror.

HTH!

Comment: Goof stuff. I'll set it up on app engine and port everything over to my tomcat instance.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Python/Django version which I deploy to Heroku.

https://github.com/dannyroa/glasstophone-django/

Comment: Cool. I'll have to look into this especially how you implemented OAuth instead of using Googles implementation.